# ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback in background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multithreading, addressbook

I have a callback handler registered that listens to changes in the iOS Address Book.This is how I register the callback

```
ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(address_book, adressBookChanged,self);
```

What I want is to perform all the commutation in background thread when callback method is called.This is how I structured my callback :

```
void adressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef ab, CFDictionaryRef info, void 
                   *context) 
{ 
   //Perform all commutation in background thread
}
```

As we can not use one addressbook ref in multiple threads .How can I perform this.Please help me out what I am doing wrong?